# Complete references of all Magento pages (for FULL test of the entire store)?

Tags: magento, themes

I'm testing my Magento store with a bought theme at Princessly.com (which I have been testing and customizing since 4 months ago). I have an obsession of testing ALL different / possible pages of a site before launching it. In most cases, the site is simple enough to have about 3 - 10 different types of pages (list page, article page, contact form page, about page, etc.) which I would go through one by one to tweak and customize into every minor detail.

However, Magento (based on Zend Framework) seems to be very versatile in having all different sorts of pages accessible from a variety of different URLs (even for the same content). Understandably, the user experience is much more sophisticated with a eCommerce site than that of a content site, thus having many more types of pages.

In addition to the problem, theme designers may not fully understand Magento. They would usually left many not-so-common pages un-designed with just default styles that would look pretty ugly to users who step on them.

My question is, **how can I find a reference / list of ALL possible Magento pages so that I can go through them one by one to make a consistenly good design throughout the entire Magento store?**

Thanks a lot! It sucks to have obsessive disorders.

Comment: Check [this article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/magento-project-guidelines-for-designers/)

Comment: In addition to the above resource - which is possibly the best - don't forget checkout/multishipping

Comment: And product reviews, individual review page, tag page, order page, order history, and lots more that ain't covered by this article...... I'm gonna kill myself!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no list of "ALL possible Magento pages". Any frontend-routable module can have any number of action controller classes under its *controllers* directory, and those classes can have any number of route-satisfying methods.

Comment: So there is in fact a place to find ALL possible satisfying URLs? Can you let me know where the controllers directory is and how to identify a route-satisfying method?

Comment: Sorry, there's a misunderstanding; by "There is no list of 'ALL possible Magento pages'" I mean that routing possibilities is essentially infinite. As for where the `controllers` directory is I can only say to open the filesystem! `app/code/[community|core|local]/*/*/controllers/`

Comment: A quick way to find controllers and their actions can be done using find/sed/grep in the command line. This won't get you rewrites but gives a quick handy overview and follows on from @benmarks suggestion. I ran this in the app/code directory.

`find ./ -type f -follow -print | grep "controllers" | sed '/Adminhtml/d' | xargs grep "public function [a-z]\+Action("`